# MVC3 dynamic number of checks in where clause

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, multiple-conditions

in my view I have a multiple select with some list of server names. Number of servers will be dynamic and change quite frequently.

```
<select name="servers" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <optgroup label="Prod5">
    <option>VS12</option>
    <option>...</option>                
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="UAT6">
    <option>VS13</option>
    <option>...</option>                        
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

In the controller I need to filter db against some static number of KPIKey and against server name(s) (kpi.KPIserver) which will be chosen by user from multiple select. How to add to the below where clause a dynamic number of KPIserver checks e.g.

where kpi.KPIkey == "CPU usage" || kpi.KPIkey == "I/O operations" && kpi.KPIserver == "VS12" || kpi.KPIserver == "VS13" || kpi.KPIserver == ...

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fs)
    {

        IEnumerable<kpi_master> allKPI = null;

        try
        {               
            allKPI = from kpi in db.kpi_masters
                     where kpi.KPIkey == "CPU usage" || kpi.KPIkey == "I/O operations"                                                  
                     select kpi;
        }
        catch (Exception e) { log.Error("KPI POST error: " + e.Message); }

        return View(allKPI);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a set number of fields you're checking, then it's easy enough.

```
var keys = new List<string>()  { "CPU usage", "I/O operations" };
var servers = new List<string>() { "VS13", "SERVERX" };

.....

allKPI = allKPI = from kpi in db.kpi_masters
                  where keys.Contains(kpi.KPIkey) || servers.Contains(kpi.KPIserver)
                  select kpi;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linq extension methods instead if the number of clauses is dynamic.
Then something like

```
var result = collection. Where (o => contional clause 1);
foreach (var extraclause in dynamicClauses)
{
    result = result.Where (o => extraclause (o));
}
```

So you can add the clauses dynamically, and the query will only execute when the collection (result) is enumerated. If you want to force the execution immediately add a

```
var final = result.ToArray ();
```